# Spring 4.0 with rest template using httpclient 4.3 gives 401 unauthorized error

Tags: spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

I use spring resttemplate to invoke an external service with basic authentication.
as below.
Have extended `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and overridden the `createHttpContext` method as below.

```
protected HttpContext createHttpContext(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
    AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
    BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
    authCache.put(this.host, basicAuth);

    // Add AuthCache to the execution context
    HttpClientContext localcontext = new HttpClientContext();
    localcontext.setAuthCache(authCache);

    if (this.appProperties.getProperty(this.userName) != null) {
        BasicCredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT,
                        AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(this.appProperties
                        .getProperty(this.userName), this.appProperties
                                .getProperty(this.password)));
        localcontext.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
    }
    return localcontext;
}
```

IN the invocation method create instance of inherited `clienthttprequestfactory`

```
    this.customFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryExtended(
            this.appProperties);

    this.restTemplate.setRequestFactory(this.customFactory)
    this.restTemplate.getForObject(url);
```

This gives me **401 unauthorized error** . 
But same code work for different service with basic authentication working fine